# Method 'IsMatch' in type 'AutoMapper.Data.DataReaderMapper' from assembly 'AutoMapper.Data, Version=1.0.0.0 does not have an implementation."

Tags: c#, list, dynamic, datatable, automapper

Just trying to figure out how to map a datatable to ienumerable.   Lots of old examples, but with 5.1.1 none of them work.  So attempting to use the prerelease of Automapper.Data

Any actual code that works for dynamically mapping.   If I need to spell everything out, what is the point of automapper?

Answer (score 4):

AutoMapper.Data does not have a version that works with 5.x. The last version it works with was in 4.2.1.

No one that uses AutoMapper.Data has wanted to step forward and update it for 5.x, so broken it sits.

Comment: is this still the case?